# sum output variable values in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, t-sql

I pass values from a Database to VB.NET using Output Variable in a stored procedure.

```
Public Sub VALUEONE()
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=XXX\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=TRUE")
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("dbo.test", conn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@test", SqlDbType.Decimal)
        cmd.Parameters("@test").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            lbl.Text = cmd.Parameters("@test").Value.ToString
            conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Now lets say i have a "800" in lbl.Text and i have exact the same code for another stored procedure (dbo.test2) and i have the outputparameter @test2 in lbl.text2 value "120". I now want to sum the "800" and "120" and visualize it in lbltest3 but i dont know how to do it. I already tried something like:

```
dim a as decimal
dim b as decimal
a = cmd.Parameters("@test").Value
b = cmd.Parameters("@test2").Value
lbl3 = (a+b).tostring
```

it doesnt work though.

Comment: Do you have the code of the stored procedure as well?

Comment: "It doesn't work." <- Can you specify what doesn't work. Do you get an error? Or don't you get the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Sub VALUETWO()
    Using conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=XXX\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=TRUE"), _
              cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("dbo.test", conn)

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@test", SqlDbType.Decimal)
        cmd.Parameters("@test").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

        conn.Open()

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Decimal a = cmd.Parameters("@test").Value

        cmd.CommandText = "dbo.test2"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@test2", SqlDbType.Decimal)
        cmd.Parameters("@test2").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Decimal b = cmd.Parameters("@test").Value

        lbl3.Text = (a + b).ToString()
     End Using
End Sub
```

Probably, though, you want to combine those stored procedures into a single call to the db.

Comment: Hi! There is still a problem. Step by step debugging shows that the right value is stored into "a" but when it comes to the second "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery" the cursor jumps to the "Catch ex as Exception" part. Any idea why?